# VS2008 Remote Debugging problems from 32-bit Windows XP client to 64-bit Windows 2008 Server

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, windows-xp, 64-bit, windows-server-2008

We are having an issue with remote dedubbing using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 on a 32 bit XP client machine and a 64 bit Windows Server 2008 Virtual Machine on Hyper-V. When we debug the web project locally we can correctly see the modules loaded in the modules window (Ctrl + Alt + U) with the relevant symbols.

When we try and debug the project remotely and attach to the process we get the yellow triangle in the breakpoint with the message ‘No symbols have been loaded and the breakpoint will not be hit’, also when we look at the modules window (Ctrl + Alt + U) the only dll’s that have been loaded are ntdll.dll, wow64.dll, wow64win.dll and wow64cpu.dll.

Can anyone confirm whether this kind of remote debugging is possible at all or does everything need to be either 32-bit or 64-bit. We have no problems on a 32-bit remote server witht he same projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [How to: Debug 64-Bit Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184681%28VS.80%29.aspx) on MSDN, 32-to-64 bit debugging should work just fine, as long as you're running the correct version of the remote debugger on the target machine:

> If you are debugging remotely, Visual
> Studio 2005 can run under WOW64 or on
> a 32-bit machine. You can debug both
> IA64 and x64 applications, as well as
> 32-bit applications running under or
> x64 WOW mode or on 32-bit platforms.
>
> To debug a 64-bit application running
> on a remote computer, you need to
> install the 64-bit remote debugger on
> the remote computer. The 64-bit remote
> debugger is available on the last disc
> of your Visual Studio 2005
> installation set.
>
> To debug
> a 64-bit application, you must use the
> correct version, which is Remote
> Debugger (x64) on the Start menu.

The correct version of the Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 Remote Debugger can be [downloaded directly from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=440ec902-3260-4cdc-b11a-6a9070a2aaab&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me too, going from 32bit XP to 64bit Win7. I am using the x64 version of msvmon.

I had great trouble setting everything up.. creating 2 identical local users, using runas to run msvmon and vs2008 as that local user, and in the end I couldn't really get the shared drive to work.. so I think I have to share a drive on the target PC, since managed assemblies have (?) a problem running from a network drive.

Strangely enough, I also had to create the appropriate directory structure on the vs-PC (c:..), even though the output went to the remote drive (c:.., but on the msvmon-PC).

Also, the first (few?) runs took severla minutes to even get started. Afterwards everything went quickly enough and well.